# A question on finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ such that $n(G/H)=0$ for some $n$. Can we derive that $H$ has finite index in $G$? ($nG$ denotes the subgroup $\{nx:x\in G\}$ for an arbitrary group $G$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $G= \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ and consider the subgroup $H$ where only the first coordinate is non-zero. Then $G/H$ has infinitely many cosets but $2(G/H)=0$.

Comment: This is a good counterexample; I am curious if it's true when we know $G$ is finitely generated? +$1$

Comment: @Clayton If $G$ is finitely generated, then so is $G/H$ and per classification of finitely generated abelian groups and the given condition we know that $G/H$ is finite.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thanks. I was pretty sure it was true, and I think I had proven something similar in one of my classes, but I couldn't recall for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Another counterexample:

Let $H$ be a group and let $G= \bigoplus \limits_{i \in I} C_i \oplus H$ where $\{ C_i \mid i \in i\}$ is an infinite family of cyclic groups of bounded order. Then $H$ is a subgroup of infinite index of $G$ and $G/H \simeq \bigoplus\limits_{i \in I} C_i$ is of bounded order.

For example, $G= \mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \cdots$ and $H= \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: This is a nice general counterexample - @Alexander's counterexample being a lovely case of this.